# Squid TLS 1.2 reverse proxy without caching

Tags: squid

Can someone familiar with squid confirm whether the following specific setup is possible:

- serve as reverse proxy only
- accept only TLS 1.2 connections from the internet facing side
- decrypts TLS 1.2 and forward to web server as clear text HTTP
- do not cache anything

Comment: Why squid? Look at haproxy.

Comment: @wurtel Does your question imply that this is specifically possible with haproxy ?

Comment: Yes, it is designed as a reverse proxy (which squid is not, although it can work as one).

Comment: HAproxy, pound, varnish, Apache, relayd for FreeBSD/OpenBSD are all more suited than Squid as a reverse proxy.